# Setting A URL Alias is changing the look of the Page

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

OK I a page that is assigned to node/4 and it looks fine:

[image: Page without URL Alias]

The client wants the URL to read Pictorial Availability or something like that.  I change the URL Alias and this is what happens:

[image]

I know in the content box they have the following:

```
<?php require_once "custom_app/cart/list_preloader.php"; ?>
```

I don't think that is the issue because when you use the default route (node/4) it loads fine.  I am trying to figure out why it puts a white space between the header and the start of the content.  Anybody have any ideas as to why this would happen?  I appreciate any input anyone may have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The screenshots weren't really enough for this. Demos links would help in the future.

When visiting the page using it's URL alias an additional CSS file is loaded (http://goo.gl/x1iKq) that gives #title a larger height, messing up spacing.

Comment: Demo links?  I can't leave the site like that.

Comment: I told you what is causing the problem. I could have told you faster if I hadn't had to Google to find the site URL first.